# es posible correr un trigger sql despues de insertar registros en una tabla dinamica

Tags: sql, trigger

muy buen dia , tengo el siguiente problema tengo  dos tablas `prueba_tmp`  y `prueba_product` ,en la cual paso  toda la información de la tabla temporal a la productiva por medio de un procedimiento almacenado.

ahora el disparador del procedimiento es un trigger que debería arrancar cuando se le ingresa toda la información a la tabla temporal  `prueba_tmp`  cuando termine de ingresar toda la información a esta tabla ejecutar el trigger para poder correr el procedimiento almacenado( todo esto lo manejo así debido a que la tabla prueba_tmp la lleno directamente desde sap) se puede correr el trigger después de que se inserte toda la informacion ?

```
USE [CTGesReport]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[triggerActualizarDatos]
   ON  [dbo].[prueba_tmp]
   AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
      EXEC [sp_procedimiento]--realiza el traspaso de la temporal a productivo
END
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Mi opinion es que eso no deberia ser un trigger.. deberia ser un proceso que dispares al terminar eso...

Comment: Los triggers no se disparan a pedido, sólo cuando se da el evento para el que se definieron. Deberías hacer simple y llanamente un procedimiento almacenado que puedas invocar más fácil (incluso desde un trigger si así lo deseas).

Comment: ¿Cómo estás llenando la tabla desde SAP?